# Envío de correo con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, email, smtp

Estoy intentando enviar un correo utilizando javascript, pero quiero hacerlo replicando la función de mail() de php.

Mi proyecto lo tengo en angular, saben si hay algún método para hacerlo de manera más parecida a esta función?

No quiero utilizar "mailto" porque es probable que la persona no tenga un correo configurado entonces esa opción no es viable para mi proyecto

Comment: Necesitas procesar el correo en el servidor, no hay una opción viable para hacerlo solo con Javascript; aún si encuentras la forma de conectar con un servidor SMTP, las credenciales quedarían visibles.

Comment: "send email from javascript smtp" y a leer y a intentar.

Comment: JavaScript en un navegador (hoy) solo puede manejar http, para enviar mails se usa smtp, imap o pop3, es decir que no se podría hacer directamente.